How is it possible that infinitesimal $h$ in IDG and infinitesimal $\varepsilon$ in SDG are the same point on axis?
There are first order infinitesimals $h$ in Infinitesimal Differential Geometry and:
$f(h)=f(0)+hf'(0)$
There are infinitesimals $\varepsilon$ that indistinguishable from zero in Synthethic Differential Geometry and:
$f(\varepsilon)=f(0)+\varepsilon f'(0)$
$h$ and $\varepsilon$ are the same point on axis. But these are different kinds of infinitesimals ($h$ has magnitude, $\varepsilon$ has no magnitude).
How is it possible? (or what's wrong in my reasoning?)

If I can make an analogy, ''mathematical theories'' might be seen as ''models'' of an underlying reality (like in physics we use mathematical models because the underlying ''reality'' is too complicated to understand fully).  Different theories might not have the same concept of ''infinitesimal'', in the same way that different ''physical models'' can have a totally different concept of ''particle'' and this does not involve any contradiction.

The incompatibility of two (or more) distinct mathematical approaches to a given problem arising from natural science or economics, etc. is a well-known phenomenon that does not surprise anybody anymore.  The lesson has been learned that a mathematical model is not a carbon copy of a pre-mathematical phenomenon, but rather has its own features that may not correspond to anything in the original phenomenon.  One well-known disagreement is between Bayesian and non-Bayesian approaches to probability/statistics.  Another is whether to account for a line in physical space by a mathematical model with or without infinitesimals.  Perhaps of similar nature is the wave-particle duality involved in accounting for light.
